# Is there an efficient algorithm for determining the probability a large randomly chosen integer is not divisible by any integer of some set?

Tags: probability-theory, randomized-algorithms, polynomial-time

Given a set of 10 integers $A = a_1, a_2, \cdots a_{10}$, is there an efficient algorithm which can tell me what's the probability a randomly chosen integer between $1$ and $10^{10}$ is *NOT* divisible by any member of this set.

I understand the Inclusion-Exclusion principle can be used to solve this problem but I can't figure out how to implement it so that it works efficiently.

**Note**: When I say "efficient", I mean polynomial time, yet I am not entirely sure what qualifies as polynomial time is this case as both variables are fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbf x$ be a random number in the range $1,\ldots,N$, and let $E_i$ denote the event that $\mathbf x$ is divisible by $a_i$. You are interested in the probability that none of the events $E_1,\ldots,E_m$ happen (in your case, $m = 10$). Using the inclusion-exclusion principle, this reduces to computing the probability of the events of the form $E_{i_1} \land \cdots \land E_{i_k}$, that is, $\mathbf x$ is divisible by all of $a_{i_1},\ldots,a_{i_k}$. Since a $\mathbf x$ is divisible by a bunch of numbers iff it is divisible by their LCM, it suffices to determine the probability that $\mathbf x$ is divisible by $a$.

Among $1,\ldots,N$, the numbers divisible by $a$ are
$$
a,2a,3a,\ldots,\lfloor N/a \rfloor a,
$$
in total $\lfloor N/a \rfloor$ numbers. Hence the probability that $\mathbf x$ is divisible by $a$ is exactly
$$
\frac{\lfloor N/a \rfloor}{N}.
$$

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what does the second subscript 1 to k mean? Is this just the notation for the inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: It's what you get when applying the inclusion-exclusion principle. If you work it out, you'll see what it means.

Comment: Ok, if I'm understanding correctly, this is basically just applying the inclusion-exclusion principle and then computing the probability for each of the resulting summands. This seems like it wouldn't be efficient though, it would run in exponential time, no?

Comment: That's right. It's exponential time in 10. But 10 is a small constant, and $2^{10}$ is only 1024.

Comment: I suppose that would be fine, yes, I am still curious if there is some optimization though

Comment: There are only 1024 cases, but also “x is divisible by p and q” means “x is divisible by lcm(p,q))” and if lcm(p,q) > N you can ignore it.